# MPI malloc() run time error

Tags: mpi

I get a run-time error when increasing the size of the block that I allocate for my array with malloc. I don't know what is the reason and hence how can I debug it.Could you help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you unless you show some code.

Comment: int *lBucket=new int[m];

Comment: Do I send all the 100+ lines?

Comment: Moreover, with 4 processes  int *Bucket = new int[m];   doesn't err,  but multiplying  m by 2 does! But 10 processes don't run into errors in the latter case!Wow...........very perplexing!

Comment: No, don't post all the code. Reduce the code to the minimum necessary to reproduce the problem.  Not only will that make it easier for SO to help, but in the process of paring it away to the bare minimum you are very likely to spot the problem yourself.

Comment: I don't  know What caused the error.

Comment: Anyway I pasted the code at:http://codepad.org/s86emRru

Comment: Looks like you're mixing up C and C++ in your code ( check header files).I don't see malloc() in your code...just 'new'.